# Newly installed 2.18.10 gives problems

Tags: qgis, installation

I recently upgraded QGis on Win 8.1 to 2.18.10 and as I opened a project file I had created before upgrading, there seems to be things that do not work.

1. Can't select any menu item. Hovering over them with the mouse doesn't highlight them and when I click on them nothing happens
2. when I try to select layers from the layers side panel, nothing happens
3. when I click on toolbar buttons, the drawing zooms out....
4. even if I do not open an old project, and try to create a new one QGis is pretty unusable like this

I see that there is a newer release. I wonder if it addresses problems of this sort or can it be that the installation/upgrading process failed somehow?

Comment: Maybe it is safer to roll back to the version you had before. Windows allows several QGIS versions in parallel.

Comment: I have upgraded QGIS many times and even if there are some minor compatibility issues I never experienced problems at this level. The problems show usually opening newer projects in older versions but not the other way around.
Try to install the newer version 2.18.11 wich has also became the new Long Term Release.

Comment: Thanks for your commnents. I installed 2.18.11...and the result was a very similar behaviour. Then after uninstalling it I reinstalled 2.18.4 and the difference is that the program now doesn't respond at all to most of the mouse clicks....very weird! I can load/unload different layers, but left mouse button commands do not receive any response, right mouse button clicks pops up a menu, scroll bars do not respond, and the program window freezes at times.....

Answer (score 1):

I finally sorted the problem out (or so I hope). By restarting my laptop QGis started to work fine. I didn't realize that I needed to do this before the software could be fully operational. So I can now run the latest release as well.